# Convert a WPF app from using EntityFramework to using WCF RESTful services

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, rest, wcf

I've followed these two walkthroughs:

- [WPF: EntityFramework MVVM Walk Through 1 Sample](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-EntityFramework-MVVM-c7167301)
- [Walkthrough: Binding WPF Controls to a WCF Data Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465161(v=vs.100).aspx)

I'm now trying to implement RESTful services in the first walkthrough code.  My attempt is at this BitBucket repository (bitbucket.org/Sryn/wpf_entityframework_wt01).

I'm stuck at the stage where I have to change the existing Linq style dB access code to using REST services, I think.  I thought it was a simple process of just changing the 'source origin' of the dB, but my understanding is that the Linq statements seem to be aware of where the data is coming from and I don't think it works with REST services.  However, I just came upon this article (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx), which I just skimmed to a particular section, entitled '**Consuming ADO.NET Data Services**'. In there it has code that looks like this:

```
BookmarkService bookmarkService = new BookmarkService(
    new Uri("http://localhost:55555/Bookmarks.svc/"));
// this generates the following URL:
// http://localhost:55555/Bookmarks.svc/Bookmarks()?$filter=substringof('WCF',Tags)&
// $orderby=LastModified
var bookmarks = from b in bookmarkService.Bookmarks
                where b.Tags.Contains("WCF")
                orderby b.LastModified
                select b;
foreach (Bookmark bm in bookmarks)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\r\n{1}", bm.Title, bm.Url);
```

.. which has both the REST service Uri and Linq statements. However, I don't know how to test/implement it.

Comment: If you're simply trying to use a web service to access your database, why not use OData WCF or WebAPI?  You can also create a RESTful WCF service that wraps your EF data layer.

Comment: Any particular articles I can follow for those suggestions?

Comment: I found this article http://www.developerhandbook.com/wcf/restful-web-service-using-wcf-1-of-3/
followed it until I've done all three parts and noticed that its got the middle Service layer (project) that's a 'translator' between the EF/data layer and the Web/jQuery layer.  I'll try to implement something similar to my needs above.